# i can't send email smtp error

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp

I'm learning now with "Pro ASP.NET MVC 4 (Professional Apress)" and when I want to compile my project receives the following error:

> SmtpException was unhandled by user code
>
> An exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' occurred in
>   System.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Failure sending mail.

This is source code:

```
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Text;
using SportsStore.Domain.Abstract;
using SportsStore.Domain.Entities;
using System.Net;

namespace SportsStore.Domain.Concrete
{

public class EmailSettings
{
    public string MailToAddress = "abc@wp.pl";
    public string MailFromAddress = "abcd@wp.pl";
    public bool UseSsl = true;
    public string Username = "abcd@wp.pl";
    public string Password = "abcd12";
    public string ServerName = "smtp.wp.pl";
    public int ServerPort = 465;
    public bool WriteAsFile = false;
    public string FileLocation = @"c:\sports_store_emails";
}

public class EmailOrderProcessor : IOrderProcessor
{
    private EmailSettings emailSettings;

    public EmailOrderProcessor(EmailSettings settings)
    {
        emailSettings = settings;
    }

    public void ProcessOrder(Cart cart, ShippingDetails shippingInfo)
    {

        using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
        {

            smtpClient.EnableSsl = emailSettings.UseSsl;
            smtpClient.Host = emailSettings.ServerName;
            smtpClient.Port = emailSettings.ServerPort;
            smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtpClient.Credentials
                = new NetworkCredential(emailSettings.Username,
                      emailSettings.Password);

            if (emailSettings.WriteAsFile)
            {
                smtpClient.DeliveryMethod
                    = SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory;
                smtpClient.PickupDirectoryLocation = emailSettings.FileLocation;
                smtpClient.EnableSsl = false;
            }

            StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder()
                .AppendLine("Nowe zamówienie")
                .AppendLine("---")
                .AppendLine("Produkty:");

            foreach (var line in cart.Lines)
            {
                var subtotal = line.Product.Price * line.Quantity;
                body.AppendFormat("{0} x {1} (wartość: {2:c}", line.Quantity,
                                  line.Product.Name,
                                  subtotal);
            }

            body.AppendFormat("Wartość całkowita: {0:c}", cart.ComputeTotalValue())
                .AppendLine("---")
                .AppendLine("Wysyłka dla:")
                .AppendLine(shippingInfo.Name)
                .AppendLine(shippingInfo.Line1)
                .AppendLine(shippingInfo.Line2 ?? "")
                .AppendLine(shippingInfo.Line3 ?? "")
                .AppendLine(shippingInfo.City)
                .AppendLine(shippingInfo.State ?? "")
                .AppendLine(shippingInfo.Country)
                .AppendLine(shippingInfo.Zip)
                .AppendLine("---")
                .AppendFormat("Pakowanie prezentu: {0}",
                    shippingInfo.GiftWrap ? "Tak" : "Nie");

            MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(
                                   emailSettings.MailFromAddress,   // od
                                   emailSettings.MailToAddress,     // do
                                   "Otrzymano nowe zamówienie!",          // temat
                                   body.ToString());                // treść

            if (emailSettings.WriteAsFile)
            {
                mailMessage.BodyEncoding = Encoding.ASCII;
            }

            smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

This is excrption details:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2146233088   Message=Failure sending mail.   Source=System
>   StackTrace:
>          at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
>          at SportsStore.Domain.Concrete.EmailOrderProcessor.ProcessOrder(Cart
>   cart, ShippingDetails shippingInfo) in
>   C:\Users\rafal\Desktop\Rozdzial07-11\SportsStore\SportsStore.Domain\Concrete\EmailOrderProcessor.cs:line
>   93
>          at SportsStore.WebUI.Controllers.CartController.Checkout(Cart cart, ShippingDetails shippingDetails) in
>   C:\Users\rafal\Desktop\Rozdzial07-11\SportsStore\SportsStore.WebUI\Controllers\CartController.cs:line
>   39
>          at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41()
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.b__7(IAsyncResult
>   _)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Object tag)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<>c__DisplayClass39.b__33()
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.b__49()
>   InnerException: 
>          HResult=-2147024893
>          Message=Could not find a part of the path 'c:\sports_store_emails\c4734a39-5267-4199-bb29-f28542b3c5ac.eml'.
>          Source=mscorlib
>          StackTrace:
>               at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>               at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share,
>   Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs,
>   String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean
>   checkHost)
>               at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions
>   options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
>               at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode)
>               at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetFileMailWriter(String pickupDirectory)
>               at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
>          InnerException:

This 2 warnings:

1. warrnig

> Warning   CS0618  'FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(string, string)' is
>   obsolete: 'The recommended alternative is to use the Membership APIs,
>   such as Membership.ValidateUser. For more information, see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=252463.'   SportsStore.WebUI   C:\Users\rafal\Desktop\Rozdzial07-11\SportsStore\SportsStore.WebUI\Infrastructure\Concrete\FormsAuthProvider.cs 10  Active

2. Warrning

> Warning       Found conflicts between different versions of the same
>   dependent assembly that could not be resolved.  These reference
>   conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to
>   detailed. SportsStore.WebUI

How to fix this?

Comment: Look at the inner exception `Could not find a part of the path 'c:\sports_store_emails\c4734a39-5267-4199-bb29-f28542b3c5ac.eml'.` Check the permissions of the app pool - can it read/write to that location?

Comment: Properly check the path !!

Comment: Thx it was problem with permissions

Answer (score 0):

```
//Create Mail body
string Emails = MailId;
string file = Server.MapPath("~/Mail.html");
//Generate Mail Body
string mailbody = "Hi"+" " +Emails;
//Whom to send email
 string to = Emails;
//Who is sending mail
string from = "Sender_Mail_Id";
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(from, to);
msg.Subject = "Auto Response Email";
msg.Body = mailbody;
msg.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
System.Net.NetworkCredential basicCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("User_EMailId", "Password");
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
client.Credentials = basicCredential;
```